# Operation on floats loses precision and changes sign

Tags: c

I have a peculiar problem. I was tasked with refactoring some old c code at work and I have run into a problem.

I have three floats arrays names VIL, ZET and GZ3D.

The values in VIL are generated with this code :

```
for(k=1;k<sommet[i];k++)
{
    if(ZET[k][i]>0)
    {
        Z=pow(10.0,ZET[k][i]/10.0);
        VIL[i]=VIL[i]+0.00344*(GZ3D[k][i]-GZ3D[k-1][i])*(float)pow(Z,(4.0/7.0))/1000.0;
    }
}
```

I have copied the function that includes the calculation and I have run it. But now when I compare the results created by the old code(which are corect) and my results I get this :

```
VIL is not equal between the two files at the index [10748]
Values "old:new" :0.079468:-0.086186
VIL is not equal between the two files at the index [10749]
Values "old:new" :0.073242:-0.085514
VIL is not equal between the two files at the index [10750]
Values "old:new" :0.070435:-0.083805
VIL is not equal between the two files at the index [10751]
Values "old:new" :0.067200:-0.081059
VIL is not equal between the two files at the index [10752]
Values "old:new" :0.063843:-0.077580
VIL is not equal between the two files at the index [10753]
Values "old:new" :0.056824:-0.072087
VIL is not equal between the two files at the index [10754]
Values "old:new" :0.054077:-0.068363
```

So the results I get are negative and always differ by ~10%.

Does anybody know what could cause this?

Comment: Please post both the old and new code.

Comment: "I have copied the function that includes the calculation." Does that mean copy/paste, or an attempt to rewrite the function?

Comment: This is the old code, I have copy/pasted.

Comment: How is `VIL` initialized? What platform(s)/toolchain(s)? Are the values of `k` involved small enough that you might post the data being used to calculate one or two of the `VIL` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double calculation as one said above and set the manual priorities to operations

```
VIL[i]=VIL[i]+ ((0.00344*(GZ3D[k][i]-GZ3D[k-1][i])) * ((float)pow(Z,(4.0/7.0))) /1000.0);
```

you should avoid if possible the operations that reduce precision: multiplication of two very big or very small values, addition or subtraction where one operand is big and second is small and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Tries to use double instead of float for casts and variables type. Double size is 8 bytes whereas float is 4.